# Add custom fields in microsoft graph calendar event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to create event using MS graph API by using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events API.

But I want to add some custom elements in request and response.

Have gone through https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/schemaextension URL but didn't get anything.

Is this possible to add request and response parameter?

If yes can anyone explain me with example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open Extension sare probably the most appropriate way of doing what you want they are pretty easy to use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/opentypeextension .

Otherwise if you trying to add properties for Legacy type applications that use MAPI (eg Outlook plugsin etc) then extended properties https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_post_singlevalueextendedproperties are the other way you could do it but you need to describe more what you want to use the extra information for in terms of the client side.